# AWS Opsworks failed to add EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I made new EC2 instance, and created new layer on Opsworks. I ran a command that displayed on Opsworks panel, but it kept failing to register on Opsworks.

Command

```
aws opsworks register --use-instance-profile --infrastructure-class ec2 --region us-east-1 --stack-id [stack id] --local
```

Error log when I ran the command in the instance

```
aws opsworks register --use-instance-profile --infrastructure-class ec2 --region us-east-1 --stack-id 50aebe6e-5aa1-4d2e-801c-b50ff1f22884 --local
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:380: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
SNIMissingWarning,
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6468k  100 6468k    0     0  28.5M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 28.5M
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Initializing AWS OpsWorks environment
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Checking if OS is supported
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Running on supported OS
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Setup motd
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: ln -sf --backup /etc/motd.opsworks-static /etc/motd
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Using assets bucket from environment: 'opsworks-instance-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com'.
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Installing Ruby for the agent
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:54 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: /tmp/opsworks-agent-installer.Xl3O6gYd9TptvPYs/opsworks-agent-installer/opsworks-agent/bin/installer_wrapper.sh -r -R opsworks-instance-assets-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 08:32:56 +0000] opsworks-init: Starting the installer
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:30 +0000] opsworks-init: Initializing AWS OpsWorks environment
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:30 +0000] opsworks-init: Setup motd
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:30 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: ln -sf /etc/motd.opsworks-static /etc/motd
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:30 +0000] opsworks-init: Checking network connectivity
healthy[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:30 +0000] opsworks-init: Recent OpsWorks agent version not yet installed, continuing.
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:31 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: mkdir -m 0755 -p /etc/chef/ohai/hints
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:31 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: touch /etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:31 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: chmod 0444 /etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json
[Thu, 14 Dec 2017 09:08:31 +0000] opsworks-init: Executing: mkdir -m 0750 -p /var/lib/aws/opsworks

[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 05:52:09 +0000] installer-wrapper: Skipping installation of opsworks-agent-ruby because it's already installed
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 05:52:09 +0000] installer-wrapper: Cleaning up
[Thu, 19 Dec 2019 05:52:09 +0000] opsworks-init: Starting the installer
/opt/aws/opsworks/releases/20160913111958_3440-20160913111958/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.65.0/lib/aws/core/credential_providers.rb:41:in `credentials':      (AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError)
Missing Credentials.
```

it said `missing credentials`, but I already configured credential. `aws-cli` version is

```
aws-cli/1.16.306 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-137-generic botocore/1.13.42
```

Also, this instance is in different VPC unlike others, so I wonder if only instances in the same VPC can be registered.

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @vargen_ well I could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue and could not really figure out the reason.

There is another way to install OpsWorks though, namely to attach a role to the EC2 instance in the management console and then run the installer on the instance. This way there is no need to run `aws configure`

[image]

Check out the details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register-registering-cli.html#registered-instances-register-registering-cli-role